# How to export nested objects from JSON lists in python

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and JSON format. I have the following JSON format in a MongoDB collection. I'd like to take the value2, value 4 from each inner object and  the value time and export them to a CSV. Also, the number of inner objects can vary from 1 to 4 objects for each document. How can I do that in python?

```
[{"object":[
    {"value1":number,
     "value2"":number,
     "value3"":number,
     "value4"":"code",
     "value5"":number,
     "value6"":"name"}
     ,
     {"value1":number,
      "value2":number,
      "value3":number,
      "value4":"code",
      "value5":number,
      "value6":"name"}]
     ,
 "time":1550666169274}]"""
```

Comment: What is the "csv output" you would like to have? did you have a look at DFS or BFS algorithms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Your formatting is syntactically incorrect. You should also (according to the rules) provide an example of what you've tried so far. You're new, so you get a pass, but keep it in mind for future =)

It's not very clear what you're asking. It seems like two questions - 1. how to access and capture the data in your data structure, 2. how to write your captured data to csv.

To answer the first part (access and capture data):
You have lists and dictionaries. To access a value in a list, you use the index number of the value you are after (starting with 0 as the first index number).

E.g. If I have the list `l = ['zero', 'one', 'two']` I can access the string 'one' by doing `l[1]`, where 1 is the index number of 'one' in the list `l`.

To access something in a dictionary, you can use it's key.
E.g. `d = {'key': 'value'}`
Use `d['key']` to get it's corresponding value - `'value'`

So assuming your data actually looks like this:

```
my_json = [
  {
    "object":[
      {
        "value1":1,
        "value2":1,
        "value3":1,
        "value4":"code",
        "value5":1,
        "value6":"name"
      },
      {
        "value1":1,
        "value2":1,
        "value3":1,
        "value4":"code",
        "value5":1,
        "value6":"name"
      }
    ],
    "time":1550666169274
  }
]
```

What you have is a list, containing dictionaries; the 'object' key's values are lists, containing dictionaries, and the 'time' key's value is a string.

So you can access the data like this:

```
my_json[0]
>>> {'object': [{'value1': 1, 'value2': 1, 'value3': 1, 'value4': 'code', 'value5': 1, 'value6': 'name'}, {'value1': 1, 'value2': 1, 'value3': 1, 'value4': 'code', 'value5': 1, 'value6': 'name'}], 'time': 1550666169274}
```

Or you can iterate over the list of objects like this useful if you have more than one object in your list):

```
for i in range(len(my_json)):
  my_json[i]
>>> {'object': [{'value1': 1, 'value2': 1, 'value3': 1, 'value4': 'code', 'value5': 1, 'value6': 'name'}, {'value1': 1, 'value2': 1, 'value3': 1, 'value4': 'code', 'value5': 1, 'value6': 'name'}], 'time': 1550666169274}
```

`my_json[0]` is a dictionary - so you can access it's value (a list of dictionaries) like this:

```
my_json[0]['object']
>>> [{'value1': 1, 'value2': 1, 'value3': 1, 'value4': 'code', 'value5': 1, 'value6': 'name'}, {'value1': 1, 'value2': 1, 'value3': 1, 'value4': 'code', 'value5': 1, 'value6': 'name'}]

my_json[0]['time']
>>> 1550666169274
```

Which is a list, so again, use indexing:

```
my_json[0]['object'][0] # or iterate through the list of objects as above
>>> {'value1': 1, 'value2': 1, 'value3': 1, 'value4': 'code', 'value5': 1, 'value6': 'name'}
```

Giving you a dictionary, so use it's key:

```
my_json[0]['object'][0]['value2']
>>> 1
```

And so on...

Since 'the number of inner objects can vary from 1 to 4 objects for each document', you really want to iterate over the list of dictionaries contained by 'object'. You can do that like this:

```
all_docs = [] # create an empty list to hold further captured data

for obj in range(len(my_json)): # for each 'thing' in this list
  obj_time = my_json[obj]['time'] # grab the time
  values_sought = [] # create an empty list to hold further captured data

  for dictionary in my_json[obj]['object']: # for each 'thing' in the 'object''s list
    val_2 = dictionary['value2'] # grab the necessary values
    val_4 = dictionary['value4']
    values_sought.append((val_2, val_4)) # append them to the empty list above

  print(obj_time, values_sought)
  >>> 1550666169274 [(1, 'code'), (1, 'code')]

  all_docs.append((obj_time, values_sought)) # append each document's data to the all_docs list

print(all_docs)
>>> [(1550666169274, [(1, 'code'), (1, 'code')])]
```

Say you have two documents (at the top level), all_docs would look like this:

```
[(1550666169274, [(1, 'code'), (1, 'code')])
 (1550666169275, [(1, 'code'), (1, 'code')]),]
```

Now you can iterate over this list and the tuples like this:

```
document_1 = all_docs[0]
document_1_data_all = all_docs[1]
document_1_data_1 = all_docs[1][0] # (or iterate)

document_2 = all_docs[1]
```

...etc

For the second part, writing to csv, it depends on how you want it formatted. I'd advise you take a look at python's inbuilt [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much. I did it with your detailed answer.